# Jquery error with script

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a script I have on my page and for some reason I get this error in the console. Here is the error.
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) "

```
!function ($) {
    //=================================== scroll  ===================================//

$body.scrollspy({
      target: '#navbar-main',
      offset: navHeight
    });

    $window.on('load', function () {
      $body.scrollspy('refresh');
    });

    $('#navbar-main [href=#]').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });


});
```

Comment: you have an extra `)` at the end

Answer (score 3):

```
!function ($) {

});
```

is a strange pattern to use, and it's not valid, it should be

```
jQuery(function($) {

});
```

If you're trying to create a DOM ready handler.
If you just need an IIFE you could do

```
!function($){ 

}(jQuery);
```

which looks like what you're trying to use here ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't write this:

```
!function ($) {

});
```

Use this :

```
$(function() {

});
```

or this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

If you want to hide all code in anonymous function , the syntax is as following:

```
(function($) {
    $body.scrollspy({
      target: '#navbar-main',
      offset: navHeight
    });

    $window.on('load', function () {
      $body.scrollspy('refresh');
    });

    $('#navbar-main [href=#]').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });


 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: its saying Uncaught ReferenceError: $body is not defined